# Why does this code give me a NameError when I run it?

Tags: python, random, nameerror

I'm trying to code a text based adventure game in Python but I can't get the battle system to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
import time   
import random    

battle_chance = 3    
enemies = ['A hoard of Goblins', 'A skeleton army',  'A large troll']
random_index = randrange(len(enemies))

def init_battle():
    while True:
        x = randint(0,5)
        time.sleep(2)
        if x == battle_chance:
            print(enemies[random_index], "Has approached you.\nWhat do you do?")
```

I always get an error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Could you paste down your error here, so it would be easier to narrow it down?

Answer (score 1):

> Error Thrown: NameError: name 'randrange' is not defined

```
random_index = randrange(len(enemies))
```

should be

```
random_index = random.randrange(len(enemies))
```

***Similarly:***

```
x = randint(0,5)
```

should be

```
x = random.randint(0,5)
```

Alternately, you can also add the below statement in the import line:

```
from random import randrange, randint
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Please upvote the answers which have helped you. You can also accept an answer which has helped you solve the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these lines:

```
random_index = random.randrange(len(enemies))

x = random.randint(0, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add at the top of your code the following line

```
from random import randrange, randint
```